# Do you design/develop a site primarily for the laptop/desktop and think about mobile later?

Tags: website-design, mobile, research, mobile-web

Do you design/develop a site primarily for the laptop/desktop and think about mobile later, or do you design your website to be mobile and unmobile friendly, therefore cutting design/dev time in half?

I'm not talking about using conditional elements to detect if someone is using a certain type of phone or a specific screen. I'm talking about being smart about site design/development and making it so you don't have to make two copies of one image, or two different CSS style sheets for mobile and non-mobile. I'm talking about thinking about your code and making it friendly to both ways of surfing the internet without any crazy coding tricks or hacks.

Comment: 3 Good reasons for mobile first [Luke Wroblewski](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?933)

Comment: Luke Wroblewski has even a book on this subject being published soon. Have a look [here](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1389), [here](http://www.lukew.com/resources/mobile_first.asp) and [here](http://www.abookapart.com/products/mobile-first).

Answer (score 1):

I Think you have to use CSS Framework that can adapt with the screen resolution. I have try it and yes there are extra step but the step is hugely reduced when using this framrwork.

See less css framework on [less framework website](http://lessframework.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brand new tutorial on responsive webdesign (template) with which you can optimize css for different screen resolutions in advance!
http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/09/12/create-a-responsive-web-design-template/

Comment: This is all well and good for sites where the content is basically just text and imagery. However the huge overhead involved with creating a full ecommerce site (for example) in this responsive fashion - tabs within pages, video content, image galleries etc - that it may be more appropriate to go for multiple templates instead of trying to create a single global one that isn't appropriate for all devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know you want to satisfy mobile devices, I'd suggest starting with those, and writing separate stylesheets for laptops/desktops. The stylesheets would be the only thing done twice, and if you keep the device-specific styles separate from the rest, it makes managing this easier. I suggest starting with the mobile device because anything that works on mobile works on large screens too. Then, you tweak the design slightly to make better use of the additional screen real estate.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use case for your site, and the business case for building the site / application in the first place. If you feel most of your most significant conversions will take place on one platform rather than another, get that built first.

Answer (score 0):

leaders of the new school say that you should:
Start from your Content Out, Mobile First. 
i think you should start from your content out, Accessibility/Mobile First